# "Lazy" lookup in Rails translatins not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization

I'm trying to implement what Rails Guides say about "lazy" translations

[image]

But I can't get it working, and I think I have everything as Guides says:

config/locales/views/es.yml

```
es:
  home:
    animals:
      header_fauna_disponible:    "Estos son los %{familia} que tenemos en estos momentos"
      header_fauna_venut:         "Estos son los %{familia} que hemos tenido"
      sense_fauna_disponible:     "En estos momentos no tenemos %{familia} disponibles"
      encarrec:                   "Si quieres un %{familia} y quieres hacer un encargo, no dudes en contactar con nosotros"
      prova:                      "prova castslla"
```

And this is my html.erb view, in the correct subfolder, and the code I use to translate:

[image]

/views/home/animals.html.erb:

```
<%= t '.prova' %>

<% if @animals_for_sale.any? %>

  <div id="animals_disponibles">

    <h1><%= t('.header_fauna_disponible',familia:@family.name.downcase) %></h1>

    <% @animals_for_sale.each do |animal| %>

      <%= render :partial => 'list_animals', locals: {animal: animal,origin:"disponibles"} %>

    <% end %>

  </div>
```

Here can see the result, of the first `<= t '.prova' %>` and `t '.header_fauna_disponible'`:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you maybe forget to set the default locale to :es? You can find that variable in config/application.rb

Also, the i18n-debug gem might be helpful to find i18n issues.

Comment: No, I didn't forget it: `config.i18n.default_locale = :es` and I have also: `config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]`

Answer (score 0):

My fault, I overwrite Translation helper badly !!!

I had a condition about if I translate a symbol or a string, to search translation in a own dictionary (datbase) or not, and "lazy" lookup uses a string !!